# Why is the representation of a vector with respect to basis an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

As part of a proof on whether any matrix represents a homomorphism between vector spaces of the appropriate dimensions with respect to any pair of bases, my professor mentioned that for the map h:V to W, the Rep of h(v) with respect to the basis D (basis of W) is an isomorphism. Earlier in the proof, the fact that Rep of v (in V) with respect to the basis B (of V) is also an isomorphism is used. Can someone please explain to me why this is true?

I know that an isomorphism is a mapping that preserves correspondence and structure, but I didn't think that a Rep was a mapping?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a $K$-vector space $X$ has a basis $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, you can define map $\phi:X\to \mathbb K^n$ by
$$
\phi(\alpha_1x_1+\cdots+\alpha_nx_n)=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n).
$$
This is

1. **Well defined**, because for a given vector the numbers $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ are unique.
2. **Linear** (easy)
3. **One-to-one**: if $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)=(\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n)$, then $\alpha_j=\beta_j$ for all $j$, and so $\alpha_1x_1+\cdots+\alpha_nx_n=\beta_1x_1+\cdots+\beta_nx_n$.
4. **Onto:** given $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)\in \mathbb K^n$, we have $$(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)=\phi(\alpha_1x_1+\cdots+\alpha_nx_n).$$

So $\phi$, which maps each vector to its coefficients in the given basis, is a vector space isomorphism between $X$ and $\mathbb K^n$.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you define the function ϕ, which is the Rep function which I'm asking about, and this maps the linear combination of the basis of the vector space X to a vector space K, which contains the coefficients of the linear combination of the basis of X. And then you show that this mapping is an isomorphism?

Comment: Yes indeed. The vector space is $\mathbb K^n$, the space of $n$-tuples of coefficients. It would be $\mathbb R^n$ if your vector space is real.

Comment: So if the some of the coefficients were complex would the K vectors space be C? (Sorry, I don't really know how to format that text properly)

Comment: It is not "some": a vector space is a vector space over a certain field. It is either $\mathbb R$, or $\mathbb C$, or some other field; but a fixed one.